# Linux Ubuntu Tomcat Best Config to avoid insufficient memory

Tags: linux, performance, tomcat, memory, amazon-ec2

I'm having memory issues in my production environment webapp.

I have a Tomcat running in a AWS EC2 t2.medium instance (2 cores cpu 64 bits + 4gb ram).

This is some info from javamelody:

```
OS: OS Linux, 3.13.0-87-generic , amd64/64 (2 cores)
Java:   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, 1.8.0_91-b14
JVM:    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 25.91-b14, mixed mode

Tomcat "http-nio-8080": Busy threads = 4 / 200     ++++++++++++ 
Bytes received = 8.051
Bytes sent = 206.411.053
Request count = 3.204 
Error count = 70 
Sum of processing times (ms) = 540.398 
Max processing time (ms) = 12.319
Memory: Non heap memory = 130 Mb (Perm Gen, Code Cache),
Buffered memory = 0 Mb,
Loaded classes = 12,258,
Garbage collection time = 1,394 ms,
Process cpu time = 108,100 ms,
Committed virtual memory = 5,743 Mb,
Free physical memory = 142 Mb,
Total physical memory = 3,952 Mb,
Free swap space = 0 Mb,
Total swap space = 0 Mb
Free disk space:    27.457 Mb
```

And my application goes into:

**There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 12288 bytes for committing reserved memory.**

I had applied the following config options, but it seems to failing again.

**export JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms1024m -Xmx3072m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"**

Is this config ok for my linux configuration?

For further information: my database and file system is running in another t2.medium instance (Windows 2 cores cpu + 4gb ram).

Thanks, and sorry for my english.

**EDITED:**

The problem is still going on. The weirdest thing is that at logs there was no big proccess running, and the time at it passed was at the very morning (so few people were connected to the application).

In the past I had the application in a Windows environment and non of this was going on. I thinked that a Linux instance would be better but I am driving crazy.

The log:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000f2d80000, 43515904, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 43515904 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/ubuntu/hs_err_pid20233.log
```

Now my config is this at **setenv.sh**:

**export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -server"**

And I don't know if makes any sense but the hs_err file have this line:

**Memory: 4k page, physical 4046856k(102712k free), swap 0k(0k free)**

Answer (score 0):

Is this config ok for your linux configuration? Well, we don't know what else is running on the machine and how much memory will be used by other processes. Thus, the answer is "it depends". However, here's what you can do to figure out the correct setting by yourself:

If you want to know right ahead that the server has enough memory, set `-Xmx` and `-Xms` to the same value. This way you'd run into OutOfMemory conditions right when you start the server, not at some randome time in the future. Maybe your OS can just allocate 2.8G instead of 3. (same with the permsize parameters in case you're still running on Java7, otherwise remove them)

You might also want to add `-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch` to the list of your parameters, so that you can be sure the memory has been allocated right from the beginning.

And lastly, you don't want to set `JAVA_OPTS` (this will be used for any start of a JVM, including the shutdown command), instead use `CATALINA_OPTS` (which will only be used for starting up tomcat)

Comment: The only big process that is running is the tomcat with the app. I've removed the PermGen as Java 8 remove that (thanks for that advice).

But, I think that something is working wrong.. Because with the "top" command I am watchin the memory and the processes, and the "free" memory starts with a big number, and starts to decrease and decrease and decrease.. I don't know why, but it's like the used memory nevers get reused.

Comment: You explicitly allow it to grow to 3072m. Until this point is reached, there's no need for reuse. That's why you should allocate all memory at once: you'll get immediate feedback if you have enough memory available or not

Comment: So I'll add explicity the same xms and xmx. Then, you say that Tomcat never release the memory that had allocated? Even if is not using it?

Comment: Part of your responsibility when tuning your system is to figure out how much memory tomcat needs. If it temporarily needs less, the superfluous memory wouldn't be handed back to the OS, no. And you'd not want it: Once tomcat needs more memory next time, you'd run into exactly the issues that you describe in your question: When the OS doesn't have enough memory left, you'll run out of memory. Or even worse, use virtual memory - which often would kill your performance.

Comment: I've added extra info from today's error. I am still getting the error.